# Firefox skips rendering text in Canvas

Tags: html, firefox, canvas, html5-canvas

Please find below jsfiddle for reference

[jsFiddle for Mozilla Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/ranu_mandan/EBmdf/)

### Javascript (FF)

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font="30px Arial";

var counter = 0;
c.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',function(event){

    draw();

    return false;

}, false);

function draw(){   

   var j = ++counter;
   for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.fillText("Hello World " + j ,10,50);
   }

 }
```

[jsFiddle for Google Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/ranu_mandan/mk5rZ/)

### Javascript (Chrome)

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font="30px Arial";

var counter = 0;
c.addEventListener('mousewheel',function(event){

   draw();

   return false;

}, false);

function draw(){   

  var j = ++counter;
  for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
   ctx.fillText("Hello World " + j ,10,50);
  }
}
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<span>Scroll on below canvas</span>
<br/>    
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="100" style="border:5px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Now try Scrolling fast using mouseWheel on canvas on above fiddles , you will find 
numbers are skipped in Firefox , whereas Google Chrome renders smoothly without skipping the numbers.

How to make rendering similar to Google Chrome in Firefox browser ?

Comment: I would highly recommend posting the code here on SO (along with the link to jsfiddle). There is a big discussion on minimizing the use of jsfiddle and write a concrete question/answer for other users to understand. Some reason being that the link could be deleted, jsFiddle changes its URL scheme, ceases to exist, gets bought and changes its name or has a big outage. Here are some links to this discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=jsfiddle

Comment: Why are you drawing the same thing 10k times?

Comment: @Steven: The OP already got this advise when he posted the question (a warning from SO actually). Instead of doing it he made sure that his fiddles aren't rendered as links so the warning shuts up. And before somebody wonders - the two fiddles are identical if you ignore indentation. Downvoting...

Comment: @Shmiddty: I am drawing nothing 10k times, just wanted to show that rendering is skiped in firefox while chrome renders smoothly.

Comment: @WladimirPalant: I have pasted the code snippnet along with jsFiddle

Comment: @RanuMandan Firefox is skipping numbers because of your for loop. You are needlessly drawing the same thing 10k times, which never releases control to the browser to update the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mk5rZ/2/

This might not be what you want, but I can't make sense of why you were drawing the same thing 10k times in your `draw` method.

```
window.requestAnimFrame = function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
};
(function wheely() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
        ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
        cnt = 0;

    ctx.font = "30px Arial";

    if ('onmousewheel' in c) c.addEventListener('mousewheel', wheeled, false);
    else c.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheeled, false);

    function wheeled(event) {
        cnt++;
        return false;
    }
    (function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.fillText("Hello World " + cnt, 10, 50);

        window.requestAnimFrame(draw);
    })();
})();​
```